# How to create a vocabulary from a list of strings in a fast manner in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a problem which I solved, but not in an efficient manner. I have a list of strings, which are captions for images. I need to get any word of this list of strings and create a dictionary containing the following information

- Word, if that word appears 5 times or more in that list
- A simple id for that word

Therefore, my vocabulary in a python dictionary would contain **word:id** entries

First, I have an auxiliary function to divide a string into tokens, or words

```
def split_sentence(sentence):
    return list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, re.split('\W+', sentence.lower())))
```

Then, I will generate the vocabulary like this, which works

```
def generate_vocabulary(train_captions):
    """
    Return {token: index} for all train tokens (words) that occur 5 times or more, 
        `index` should be from 0 to N, where N is a number of unique tokens in the resulting dictionary.
    """  
    #convert the list of whole captions to one string
    string=listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in train_captions]) 

    #divide the string tokens (individual words), by calling the previous function 
    individual_words=split_sentence(string)

    #create a list of words that happen 5 times or more in that string  
    more_than_5=list(set([x for x in individual_words if individual_words.count(x) >= 5]))

    #generate ids
    ids=[i for i in range(0,len(more_than_5))] 

    #generate the vocabulary(dictionary)
    vocab = dict(zip(more_than_5,ids))

    return {token: index for index, token in enumerate(sorted(vocab))}
```

The code works like a charm for relatively small lists of captions. However, with lists with thousands of lengths (e.g., 80000), it lasts forever. I am running this code for one hour now.

Is there any way to speed up my code? how can I calculate my more_than_5 variable faster?

**EDIT: I forgot menstioning that, in very few specific members of this list of strings, there are \n symbols in just some elements at the beginning of the sentence. Is that possible to eliminate just this symbol from my list and then apply the algorithm again?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate a number of word's occurrences once instead of calculating it on every step of list comprehension using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) package.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def split_sentence(sentence):
    return list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, re.split('\W+', sentence.lower())))

def generate_vocabulary(train_captions, min_threshold):
    """
    Return {token: index} for all train tokens (words) that occur min_threshold times or more, 
        `index` should be from 0 to N, where N is a number of unique tokens in the resulting dictionary.
    """  
    #convert the list of whole captions to one string
    concat_str = ' '.join([str(elem).strip('\n') for elem in train_captions]) 
    #divide the string tokens (individual words), by calling the split_sentence function 
    individual_words = split_sentence(concat_str)
    #create a list of words that happen min_threshold times or more in that string  
    condition_keys = sorted([key for key, value in Counter(individual_words).items() if value >= min_threshold])
    #generate the vocabulary(dictionary)
    result = dict(zip(condition_keys, range(len(condition_keys))))
    return result

train_captions = ['Nory was a Catholic because her mother was a Catholic, and Nory’s mother was a Catholic because her father was a Catholic, and her father was a Catholic because his mother was a Catholic, or had been.',
                  'I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I wasn’t really happy.',
                  'Almost nothing was more annoying than having our wasted time wasted on something not worth wasting it on.']

generate_vocabulary(train_captions, min_threshold=5)
# {'a': 0, 'because': 1, 'catholic': 2, 'i': 3, 'was': 4}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! just another thing that I forgot mentioning. At the beginning of some strings in the list of strings, there are \n strings. How can I eliminate this specific symbol (keeping the rest of the sentence) and apply the algorithm again? Thank you again.

Comment: @mad, you can strip '\n' from begin and end of string using str.strip() method. There's update in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Eduard Ilyasov said, the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class is the best when needing to count things.

Here's my solution:

```
import re
import collections

original_text = (
    "I say to you today, my friends, though, even though ",
    "we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have ",
    "a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American ",
    "dream. I have a dream that one day this nation will rise ",
    'up, live out the true meaning of its creed: "We hold these ',
    'truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal."',
    "",
    "I have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia ",
    "sons of former slaves and the sons of former slave-owners ",
    "will be able to sit down together at the table of brotherhood. ",
    "I have a dream that one day even the state of ",
    "Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, ",
    "sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed ",
    "into an oasis of freedom and justice. ",
    "",
    "I have a dream that my four little chi1dren will one day ",
    "live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color ",
    "of their skin but by the content of their character. I have ",
    "a dream… I have a dream that one day in Alabama, ",
    "with its vicious racists, with its governor having his lips ",
    "dripping with the words of interposition and nullification, ",
    "one day right there in Alabama little black boys and black ",
    "girls will he able to join hands with little white boys and ",
    "white girls as sisters and brothers. "
    )

def split_sentence(sentence):
    return (x.lower() for x in re.split('\W+', sentence.strip()) if x)

def generate_vocabulary(train_captions):
    word_count = collections.Counter()

    for current_sentence in train_captions:
        word_count.update(split_sentence(str(current_sentence)))

    return {key: value for (key, value) in word_count.items() if value >= 5}

print(generate_vocabulary(original_text))
```

I made some assumptions that you didn't specified:

- I didn't think that a word would span two sentences
- I kept the fact that your captions aren't going to be always strings. If you know they will always be you can simply the code by changing `word_count.update(split_sentence(str(current_sentence)))` to `word_count.update(split_sentence(current_sentence))`